# Adding a expense category to transfer

Tags: gnucash, transfer

I added a category to transfer a few years ago but I can't figure out how to do it now in GnuCash. How can I tag a transfer with an expense category?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "tag a transfer with an expense category".

Comment: A transfer *is* to an expense category, at least if it's an expense. Can you explain more about what it is that you're trying to do?